# Swift VC with two tables and two NSFetchedResultsController - How do I differ from each other?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

programming in Swift 4.2 here.
I have a View Controller with 2 TableViews, each one controlled by a  NSFtchedResultsController and each Controller gets it's own data from a core-data table.

My problem is: on the delegate methods from NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, how can I differ witch one is being updated, so I can update the right tableview ? Since they are on the same VC, there are just one delegate for Both.

If you need some code, I'm glad to post here, but I think it is desnecesary, I'm the standard ones for the delegate core-data and TableViews

Thank you !

Comment: The first argument (`controller`) to each of the delegate methods is the calling FRC - just compare that to the two FRCs (which are presumably properties of the view controller) and update the corresponding table.

Comment: Oh, of course ! They point to the same object ! Thank you !